# Need clarification in 8086 Assembly, what does a register contain after loading a BCD number into it?

Tags: emu8086

Using 8086 Assembly:

I've been given an assignment that asks me the specific contents of registers after using the following commands. I will ;comment what I believe is true, but I am probably 100% wrong.

MOV AH,0

```
        AX = 0000 0000 0000 0000   AH = 0000 0000   AL = 0000 0000
        or are they equal to AX = 0000H   AH = 00H   AL = 00H ?
```

MOV AL,9

```
        AX = 0000 0000 0000 1001   AH = 0000 0000   AL = 0000 1001
        or AX = 0009H   AH = 00H   AL = 09H ?
```

MOV AL,7

```
        AX = 0000 0000 0000 0111   AH = 0000 0000   AL = 0000 0111
        or AX = 0007H   AH = 00H   AL = 07H ?
```

AAA

```
        AX = 0000 0000 0000 0111   AH = 0000 0000   AL = 0000 0111
        or AX = 0007H   AH = 00H   AL = 07H ?
```

Am I wrong to assume that registers always only contain binary information? I was told that they are 8 bit (with the exception of a few others and if you combine AL and AH you get AX which is 16-bit) which makes me believe that they have to only carry binary.

Also, I assume that after the AAA command the contents of AX, AH, and AL do not change because the registers are in binary, or does it change it  to its ASCII number (in hex) which in this particular case will also be 7?

For a different question:

I also have a question about a command that I could use instead of MOV.
For example, I would like to use something that replaces MOV AH,0.
I have tried LEA AH,0 , but I have to offset the memory addresses and I'm not sure on how to proceed with that.

Thank you for any help!

I've researched the AAA command, but I only find information on what happens after using AAA after an ADD command, not when there is no ADD command.

Comment: I recommend looking at an [Instruction Set Architecture documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/). It describes what each of the instructions does. You can XOR a value to itself and it will always give zero. If you XOR a register to itself it is always zero. `xor ah, ah` will zero AH register.

Comment: Registers contain binary data and they have specific sizes. You can represent that binary data in many ways, for example in 2-base binary, decimal, or hexadecimal. They’re just representations and don’t affect the operation in any way. So both sides of your ORs are true.